# GCP Cloud Composer - files in data folder

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x, gcsfuse

My dag generator file generates ~100 dags based on `dag_params.json` file which holds information about each dag - dag_id, schedule and all information required to execute tasks properly. Dag generator and `dag_params.json` files are available in *dags/* folder.

Additionally there is a *dags/ELT/* folder with sql files, json files with schemas etc. (~2000files). Files from *dags/ELT/* folder are mapped to tasks in dags based on `dag_params.json` file:

```
"market": {
                "dag_id": "dag1",
                "bucket": "bucket1",
                "bq_dataset": "ds1",
                "sqls": [
                    {
                        "file_name": "query1.sql",
                        "file_path": "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/ELT/folder/sqls/query1.sql",
                        "file_path_template": "/folder/sqls/query1.sql"
                    },
                    {
                    ...
                    }
                ]
            }
```

So as an example, I use file_path_template value in `BigQueryInsertJobOperator` templated field to execute query.

Environment: `composer-2.0.23-airflow-2.2.5`

I would like to move *dags/ELT/* folder to *data/ELT/* folder. To make it work properly in dag generator I have defined `template_searchpath=/home/gcs/airflow/data/ELT/` and everything worked as expected. However, it seems like this change generates much more gcs operations (~3 times more) which increase costs. What is the cause of this increase?

Logs show thousands of these:

[image]

Documentation https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/cloud-storage says thare are different types of data synchronization in *dags/* and *data/* folders. Based on my understanding files like table schemas, sql queries should be placed in *data/* but if it increases storage cost by default (operations), maybe it is easier (and cheaper?) to increase machines in environment and keep it in *dags/* folder instead.